# Repeated measures

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss

I have administered an instrument (4 subscales, total items 32, no. of items in each subscale 12, 7, 9 & 4) three times over an year. I have worked out the factor scores. I am not sure if I should compare means or go GENERAL LiNEAR MODEL, then REPEATED MEASURE. I need to know which way to go and why, also the steps in SPSS.

Comment: Could you provide more details of the experimental design and your hypotheses?

Comment: The study aims to investigate change over time in the attitude of middle school students towards mathematics. The subscales are Self Confidence, Value Enjoyment and Motivation. The hypothesis would be that there is significant change in attitude as students experience challenging mathematical experience during middle school.Thank you so much for responding to my query

Comment: Ho: The attitude of students toward mathematics is the same across repeated measures. 
H1: The attitude of students toward mathematics is  different across repeated measures

Answer (score 1):

With data from the same individuals at each time point, you should use a repeated measures design, as the observations are not independent.